# Why don't view debug rows that generates by System.debug() method in Salesforce?

Tags: debugging, salesforce, apex-code

I have created a batchable class for a production system. If following code doesn't work, any code does not work.

The code is in production system now. It takes daily exchange rates from a site everyday and creates Currency__c records. If it works when exchange rates haven't published, it takes last day exchange rates. But it does not work the way I want and I would like to test it at debug logs.

Following method "**getXML(Date today)**" has never invoked when I viewed debug logs. Therefore **System.debug('test: ' + result);** has also never invoked.

How can I see this log?

```
public String getXML(Date today){  
    counter += 1;       
    if(counter == 11) return '';
    try{
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();       

        String m = today.month() + '';
        if((today.month()+'').length()==1) m = '0' + today.month();
        String d = today.day() + '';
        if((today.day()+'').length()==1) d = '0' + today.day();
        String donem = today.year() + '' + m;
        String formattedDate = d + '' + m + today.year();

        req.setEndpoint('http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/' + donem + '/' + formattedDate + '.xml'); 
        req.setMethod('GET');            
        String result = '';
        if (!Test.isRunningTest()){
            HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
            result = res.getBody();
        }
        else {
            result += 'test';
        }         
        System.debug('test: ' + result);
        if(res.getStatusCode()==404){
            return getXML(today.addDays(-1));
        }   
        return result;
    }catch(Exception e){
        return getXML(today);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question it is this "you have some code with debug statements in it. If you run this code by itself you see these statements. If you run it as part of a larger test the debug statements do not appearing; leading you to think the actions did not take place".

I hit a similar problem and talk about it on my blog http://sforcehacks.blogspot.ca/2014/01/debug-statements-stopped-working-on.html

Essentially, when the total size of the trace file gets too large then Salesforce seems to drop debug statements; even those that are to be logged at the Error level.

In your case I would not rely on debug statements to follow what is happening in your batch process.  Instead create a temporary object (table) and store a record in it for each time your getdate method is called.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the developer console open it should capture the logs for a running batch.

Alternatively, try following the steps under [Monitor Debug Logs](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/code_monitoring_debug_logs.htm):

> To view saved debug logs, click **Your Name | Setup | Monitoring | Debug
>   Logs.**
>
> From this page, click New to specify a user that you want to
>   retain debug logs for.
>
> After you have started retaining debug logs, you can:
>   * Click View to view a specific log's details.
>   * Click Download to download the debug log as an XML file.

I find it helpful to have some batch jobs send an email with there BatchableContext Status on completion - See [Sending a notification when Batch Apex completes](http://www.fishofprey.com/2012/03/salesforce-sending-notification-when.html).

Finally, your Exception handling could create a recursive loop depending on what is causing the exception. I guess that is what `counter` is guarding against. One possibility is an exception is occurring before the code reaches the expected debug lines. Try putting a debug line in the exception handling with `LoggingLevel.Error` as the first argument.

If you are unable to see your logging messages as the log is getting too big, try reducing the logging level and changing the important logging messages to be either INFO or ERROR level.

E.g.

```
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.Error, 'Exception:' + e);
    return getXML(today);
}
```

Comment: I know the way but debug log too large. its size is 2,451,489 byte. Likely some of it is truncated, therefore I don't all of the them.

Comment: All of the log filters are selected "none", except "apex code" in Detail page of the class -> Log Filters. When I call the class by visualforce page, log is created nicely. But when I scheduled it, log isn't created. Can you help me please?

Comment: @mustafatop Try increasing the `LoggingLevel` on the important lines and then setting the apex code log filter accordingly. This should greatly reduce the log size if you use Info, warn or Error.

Comment: I have tried LoggingLevel but still can not see that I want to see, when I have scheduled the batchable class. But same LoggingLevel, when I use the batchable class as controller class and call by visualforce page, I can see that I want to see.

Comment: @mustafatop Can you not see the log file at all when running as batchable or is the log file too long?

Comment: I don't see when running as batchable